# Meaning of command to system consisting of only pathnames and -C flag

Tags: python, shell, command

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm a physicist and not a programmer so bear with me. I'm debugging an image registration demo with a GUI, and somewhere along the way things go wrong. The demo works fine on the machine it was originally written on, but both that machine and mine are Windows 7 64-bit machines. The specifics of the entire code or it's purpose really aren't that important, I've narrowed down the error to the following parts of code:

```
def targetConvert(self):
    self.targetExtHeader = '.'+self.targetText.GetValue().split('.')[-1]
    self.targetExtBinary = self.getBinaryFileExtension( self.targetExtHeader )

    self.targetFile = 'target_org'+self.targetExtHeader

    # split 4D data sets, currently available only when .par file format
    # is used
    if self.targetExtHeader == '.par' or self.targetExtHeader == '.PAR':
        self.logOutput.AppendText('Split target to multiple 3D images and store in tmp/ folder.\n')
        cmd = []
        cmd.append(self.lreg + ' -C ' + '\"'+self.targetText.GetValue()+'\"' + ' ' + '\"'+self.tmpFolder + self.targetFile+'\"')            

        print '\n\n\n'+cmd[0]+'\n\n\n'
        self.executeCommandList(cmd)
        ...

def executeCommandList(self, cmd):

    self.busyLabel.SetLabel(' Busy ')
    self.busyLabel.SetBackgroundColour('Red')
    self.Layout()
    self.Refresh()

    for i in range(0,len(cmd)):
        self.logOutput.AppendText( '\nCommand(s):\n' )
        self.logOutput.AppendText( cmd[i] )
        self.logOutput.AppendText( '\n\n' )
        self.process = subprocess.Popen( cmd[i], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
        while self.process.poll() is None:
            line = self.process.stdout.readline()
            self.logOutput.AppendText( line )

        # wait a second
        time.sleep(0.1)

    self.busyLabel.SetLabel('Ready')
    self.busyLabel.SetBackgroundColour(self.backgroundColorPanel)
    self.Layout()
    self.Refresh()
```

The command that is passed to the system in cmd[i] in executeCommandList is:

```
"C:\Users\310079322.CODE1\Documents\Thesis\regDemo\\lreg\\lreg.exe" -C "C:\Users\310079322.CODE1\Documents\Thesis\regDemo\ParrecImgsForRegisration\WIP_SSh_DWI_FAST_SENSE_8_1.PAR" "C:\Users\310079322.CODE1\Documents\Thesis\regDemo\\tmp\\target_org.PAR"
```

Google hasn't been able to explain to me what the purpose of this command is, but I don't think it's working. My gut feeling is that it should copy the *targetFile* to *self.tmpFolder*, but I'm not sure, since for the source file none of this subprocess.open stuff seen in the executeCommandList method was used, but instead, the file sourceConvert took care of it directly like this:

```
def sourceConvert(self):
    self.sourceExtHeader = '.'+self.sourceText.GetValue().split('.')[-1]
    self.sourceExtBinary = self.getBinaryFileExtension( self.sourceExtHeader )

    self.sourceFile = 'source'+self.sourceExtHeader
    self.logOutput.AppendText('Copy source T2 to tmp/ folder.\n')

    shutil.copyfile(self.sourceText.GetValue()[:-4] + self.sourceExtHeader, self.tmpFolder + self.sourceFile[:-4] + self.sourceExtHeader)
```

Can anyone help me shed some light on this issue, i.e., what is the command passed to the shell through the executeCommand-method supposed to do, and what could be the problem with the implementation that I'm experiencing?

Best regards,
Mikael

Comment: You are running `lreg.exe`. We don't know what this program is, but the code as such looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always give a try to ask lreg.exe itself; run cmd.exe from windows start menu, get into folder where lreg.exe exists, and run it with -h parameter, like this one:

`cd \Users\310079322.CODE1\Documents\Thesis\regDemo\lreg [hit enter]
lreg.exe -h`

if lreg.exe supports commandline help, you should see all the options explained, and -C option among them; it's not sure, but it's often worth a shot.

G.

Comment: Thanks you, one question out of the way at least! Somehow I missed that the first path was a .exe-file, and just assumed it was one of the data files, so that explains why I couldn't tell the command is supposed to run a program.

Comment: The longer the commandline - the harder to find what's happening :) Just noticed -C option syntax - that means there should be some other options.